# Need to add keepress event for a variable

Tags: jquery, variables, slider

I want combine keyboard left arrow event for this var $prev.

I have tried var

```
$prev = $('<div class="myslide"></div>') || event.keypres == 37 ;
```

not working ...

any suggestions?

please help me how to add another event with this variable

```
var $prev = $('<div class="myslide"></div>') ;
```

Thankyou..

Answer (score 0):

Please change the typo:

```
prev = $('<div class="myslide"></div>') || event.keypress == 37 ;
var prev = $('<div class="myslide"></div>') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Atbev/

feel free to add your OR `||` condition.

this demo should help,

**code**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // not sure if you will need this but it should stop horizontal scrolling
    if(e.keyCode === 37) {
        alert(" Hi I am left arrow");
        $("#previous").click();
    } else if(e.keyCode === 39) {
        alert(" Hi I am right arrow");
        $("#next").click();
    }
});
```